# jQuery toggle messing up page position

Tags: jquery, html, html-table, toggle

I have this table of movie titles, and inside the cell with with the title is a hidden div. Inside the div, I have placed text containing a summary of the movie. I want users to be able to toggle the movie summaries. So far, the toggle button is working. Unfortunately, whenever the button is clicked, the position on the page jumps.

Is there a way to use the toggle capability without making the page position jump?

EDIT:

Here's my toggle code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#button1").click(function(){
        $("p.desc").toggle();
     });
});
```

Here's a sample HTML:

```
<button id="button1">Toggle Summaries</button>
<table border="1">
    <tr>
       <th>Title</th>
       <th>Release Date</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>2001: A Space Odyssey
          <div><p class="desc"><!--Summary of movie here--></p></div>
       </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What exactly can anyone tell you?... we cannot see your page or your code!

Comment: Sorry, guys, I'm a bit new SO. I'll put a snippet of code up.

Comment: Where is `p.desc` when you have class `desc` on a `div`?  Where is `#button1`?  So far, your posted code is not helping clarify anything here.

Comment: Putting `div`'s inside of `table`'s is not a good practice.

Comment: So should I take out the `div` and leave the `p`?

Comment: Here is a working demo of your exact code... http://jsfiddle.net/XJH3M/  Perhaps you can explain better what the issue is here... I do not see anything changing position.

Comment: No, leave the `div` and the `p` and remove the `table`, IMHO.  If you decide to keep the `table`, remove the `div` & `p` and just put a `span` around the text and target that with the jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

Call the [`preventDefault`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) function at the beginning of your toggle anchor's click handler. That will stop the link from firing its default click action (I would guess you set your `href="#"` and its jumping to the top of the current page).

```
$('#summary-toggle').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    // Your toggling code
});
```

Thanks to Sparky672 for the tip on `preventDefault`. Returning `false` from an event handler is not the best way to stop the default action.

Comment: `.click(function(e){ e.preventDefault(); // toggle code; });` would be the more modern way.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3498492/javascriptvoid0-vs-return-false-vs-preventdefault

Comment: The Maniac, `e.preventDefault();` should be the very _first_ line of the function, not the last.  See the example code on the [jQuery page you linked](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/), as well.

Comment: This is now a good answer.  If we ever find out that it's applicable to this particular question... I'll up-vote it too.