# How to stopPropagation() within a jquery plugin? (updated)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

> (I had to rewrite the whole question in order to clarify it, some
>   older answers may not match the content entirely)

I have here two fiddles created to demo the problem.

When you click on a table row an alert will show up.

However this alert should not show up when clicking on the "more" button.

The working example is correctly illustrated [here](http://jsfiddle.net/houmie/AZYAP/1/)

However when I make a plugin from this feature, the stopPropagation() doesn't work any longer and I still get the alert shown when I click on the "more" button, as illustrated [here](http://jsfiddle.net/houmie/XbK33/1/)

The Plugin:

```
$.fn.shorten = function(settings) {

   var config = $.extend( {
     showChars : 100,
     ellipsesText : "...",
     moreText : "more",
     lessText : "less"
    }, settings);

$(document).off('click', '.morelink').on('click', '.morelink', function(e){ 
    e.preventDefault(); 
    e.stopPropagation();    

  var $this = $(this);

  // Toggle del nombre del link
  if ($this.hasClass('less')) { // clic en more para mostrar less

    $this.removeClass('less');
    $this.html(config.moreText);

    // muestro shorcontent y escondo allcontent
    $this.parent().prev().prev().show(); // shortcontent
    $this.parent().prev().hide(); // allcontent

  } else { // click en less para mostrar more

    $this.addClass('less');
    $this.html(config.lessText);

    $this.parent().prev().prev().hide(); // shortcontent
    $this.parent().prev().show(); // allcontent
  }

  return false;
});

return this.each(function() {
  var $this = $(this);

  var content = $this.html();
  if (content.length > config.showChars) {
    var c = content.substr(0, config.showChars);
    if (c.indexOf('<') >= 0) // If there's HTML don't want to cut it
    {
      var inTag = false; // I'm in a tag?
      var bag = ''; // Put the characters to be shown here
      var countChars = 0; // Current bag size
      var openTags = []; // Stack for opened tags, so I can close them later

      for (i=0; i<content.length; i++)
      {
        if (content[i] == '<' && !inTag)
        {
          inTag = true;

          // This could be "tag" or "/tag"
          tagName = content.substring(i+1, content.indexOf('>', i));

          // If its a closing tag
          if (tagName[0] == '/')
          {
            if (tagName != '/'+openTags[0]) console.log('ERROR en HTML: el tope del stack debe ser la tag que cierra');
            else
              openTags.shift(); // Pops the last tag from the open tag stack (the tag is closed in the retult HTML!)
          }
          else
          {
            // There are some nasty tags that don't have a close tag like <br/>
            if (tagName.toLowerCase() != 'br')
              openTags.unshift( tagName );// Agrega al inicio el nombre de la tag que abre
          }
        }
        if (inTag && content[i] == '>')
        {
          inTag = false;
        }

        if (inTag) bag += content[i]; // Add tag name chars to the result
        else
        {
          if (countChars < config.showChars)
          {
            bag += content[i];
            countChars ++;
          }
          else // Ya tengo los caracteres necesarios
          {
            if (openTags.length > 0) // Tengo tags sin cerrar
            {
              console.log('Quedaron tags abiertas');
              console.log(openTags);
              for (j=0; j<openTags.length; j++)
              {
                console.log('Cierro tag '+ openTags[j]);
                bag += '</'+ openTags[j] +'>'; // Cierro todas las tags que quedaron abiertas

                // You could shift the tag from the stack to check if you end with an empty stack, that means you have closed all open tags
              }
              break;
            }
          }
        }
      }
      c = bag;
    }

    var html = '<span class="shortcontent">' + c + '&nbsp;' + config.ellipsesText +
               '</span><span class="allcontent">' + content +
               '</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="morelink badge">' + config.moreText + '</a></span>';

    $this.html(html);
    $(".allcontent").hide(); // Esconde el contenido completo para todos los textos
  }
});
```

};

Comment: `.live()` is deprecated.

Comment: Just a little note. jQuery 1.9 has removed the method `live()` so I would start using the method `on()` instead.

Comment: there must be a callback function in your plugin...use your code there.

Comment: ah I see. do I just do a .off('click').on('click') ?

Comment: nope, $(document).on('click', '.morelink', function(e){ e.preventDefault(); e.stopPropagation(); })

Comment: on for live in jquery 1.9

Comment: `$('.morelink').on('click', function(event) {
     event.preventDefault();
       event.stopPropagation();`  I tried that now. Still no joy.

Comment: @Kave, nope. As of jQuery 1.7, it's `$(document).on('click', '.morelink', function(evt) { evt.preventDefault(); evt.stopPropagation(); ... });` instead of `$('.morelink').live('click', function(){ ... });`

Comment: Thanks guys, I have clarified the problem with two fiddles. Please see updated question.

Answer (score 3):

Not only can  you use `return false;` but you can also use `JavaScript:void(0)`.

[Check here for the difference between the two.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3498492/javascriptvoid0-vs-return-false-vs-preventdefault)

Although `stopPropogation()` and `preventDefault()` are different, `return false` performs both.

Finally `.live()` is depreciated, us `on()` instead: http://api.jquery.com/on/

---

You could try:

```
$('body').on('click', '.morelink', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      ...
}
```

---

Here's a hacky *temporary* change to get it working as you want, until you find a more permanent solution. Hey, it may even be a jQuery bug, I don't know. Either way, this allows clicking on the td to execute the alert, and clicking on the dropdown (more/less) not to.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#tab_open_deals tbody tr td').off('click').on('click', function(e) {
    var $target = $(e.target);
    if($target.is(".morelink"))
    {
        // You clicked the morelink. Do nothing.
    }
    else
    {
        // Do your stuff!       
    }

});
```

Comment: Thanks Jimbo, I have clarified the problem with two fiddles. Please see updated question.

Comment: @Kave I've done something probably awful and hacky.. basically checking that you're NOT clicking on the more/less dropdown before continuing with the alert. Would this be useful or is it not what you want?

Comment: yeah better than nothing. It seems no one else has any other idea. lol :) I am amazed that there is no real solution

Comment: @Kave It's awful, but allows you to continue with your code until you find a more permanent solution.

Comment: Thanks for your help. +1 from me. I leave that open until a proper solution is found though. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What browser?

Try this:

```
if(event.stopPropagation) event.stopPropagation();
if(event.preventDefault) event.preventDefault();
return false;
```

Comment: `stopPropagation()` and `preventDefault()` are 2 entirely different things.

Comment: Then you might also need to add `event.cancelBubble = true` and `event.returnValue = false`

Comment: Thanks, I have clarified the problem with two fiddles. Please see updated question.

Answer (score 1):

You could try and add the following on the href attribute href="reurn false;"
or you could locate the click eventhandler - function that is being called and at the end of your code add return false; Or change tha A tags completely to something else..

Comment: Thanks, I have clarified the problem with two fiddles. Please see updated question.