# Clicking link with anchor # not go to top of the pages

Tags: javascript, html

I have a link as follows

```
<a href='#'>click to update the page</a>
```

What the link does it that it triggers a JavaScript code to update the contents of a div without posting back to the server.
The problem is that when I click the link, it always go to the top to the page due to  `href='#'`. Is it possible to avoid this movement?

Comment: I often use `span`s instead of `a`s for this purpose

Comment: All methods -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3498492/javascriptvoid0-vs-return-false-vs-preventdefault

Answer (score 5):

Quick and dirty.

```
<a href='javascript:void(0)'>
```

You can also use CSS to simulate a hyperlink hand without using `<a>`.

```css
cursor: pointer;
```

Comment: Or even just `<a href="javascript:">`

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
<a href='javascript:void(0)'>click to update the page</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid to post the link by following code:

```
<a href='javascript:void(0);'>click to update the page</a>
```

use it the page will not be refresh by this.