# Calling toastr makes the webpage jump to top of page

Tags: javascript, toastr

I'm seeking a solution for the toastr.js "error" that causes the webpage, if scrolled down, to jump up again when a new toastr is displayed

[GitHub page containing the script](https://github.com/CodeSeven/toastr)

I've tried to change the top to auto, but that wasn't an accepted parameter, because nothing showed up then.

Isn't there any way to make it appear where the mouse is at the moment?

```
.toast-top-center {
  top: 12px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  left: 43%;
}
```

this has the calling code:

```
 <p><span style="font-family:'Roboto','One Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif;color:rgb(253,253,255); font-size:16px ">


<a href="#" style="color: rgb(255,0,0,0)" onclick="playclip()">xxxxxxxxxxxxx </a> 
</span></p>
```

This is the function code:

```
<script type='text/javascript'> function playclip() { 
toastr.options = {
  "debug": false,
  "positionClass": "toast-top-center",
  "onclick": null,
  "fadeIn": 800,
  "fadeOut": 1000,
  "timeOut": 5000,
  "extendedTimeOut": 1000
}
toastr["error"]("This link is pointing to a page that hasn't been written yet,</ br> sorry for the inconvenience?"); } </script>
```

And this is the script itself:
/*

```
 * Toastr
 * Copyright 2012-2015
 * Authors: John Papa, Hans Fjällemark, and Tim Ferrell.
 * All Rights Reserved.
 * Use, reproduction, distribution, and modification of this code is subject to the terms and
 * conditions of the MIT license, available at http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
 *
 * ARIA Support: Greta Krafsig
 *
 * Project: https://github.com/CodeSeven/toastr
 */
/* global define */
(function (define) {
    define(['jquery'], function ($) {
        return (function () {
            var $container;
            var listener;
            var toastId = 0;
            var toastType = {
                error: 'error',
                info: 'info',
                success: 'success',
                warning: 'warning'
            };

            var toastr = {
                clear: clear,
                remove: remove,
                error: error,
                getContainer: getContainer,
                info: info,
                options: {},
                subscribe: subscribe,
                success: success,
                version: '2.1.3',
                warning: warning
            };

            var previousToast;

            return toastr;

            ////////////////

            function error(message, title, optionsOverride) {
                return notify({
                    type: toastType.error,
                    iconClass: getOptions().iconClasses.error,
                    message: message,
                    optionsOverride: optionsOverride,
                    title: title
                });
            }

            function getContainer(options, create) {
                if (!options) { options = getOptions(); }
                $container = $('#' + options.containerId);
                if ($container.length) {
                    return $container;
                }
                if (create) {
                    $container = createContainer(options);
                }
                return $container;
            }

            function info(message, title, optionsOverride) {
                return notify({
                    type: toastType.info,
                    iconClass: getOptions().iconClasses.info,
                    message: message,
                    optionsOverride: optionsOverride,
                    title: title
                });
            }

            function subscribe(callback) {
                listener = callback;
            }

            function success(message, title, optionsOverride) {
                return notify({
                    type: toastType.success,
                    iconClass: getOptions().iconClasses.success,
                    message: message,
                    optionsOverride: optionsOverride,
                    title: title
                });
            }

            function warning(message, title, optionsOverride) {
                return notify({
                    type: toastType.warning,
                    iconClass: getOptions().iconClasses.warning,
                    message: message,
                    optionsOverride: optionsOverride,
                    title: title
                });
            }

            function clear($toastElement, clearOptions) {
                var options = getOptions();
                if (!$container) { getContainer(options); }
                if (!clearToast($toastElement, options, clearOptions)) {
                    clearContainer(options);
                }
            }

            function remove($toastElement) {
                var options = getOptions();
                if (!$container) { getContainer(options); }
                if ($toastElement && $(':focus', $toastElement).length === 0) {
                    removeToast($toastElement);
                    return;
                }
                if ($container.children().length) {
                    $container.remove();
                }
            }

            // internal functions

            function clearContainer (options) {
                var toastsToClear = $container.children();
                for (var i = toastsToClear.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                    clearToast($(toastsToClear[i]), options);
                }
            }

            function clearToast ($toastElement, options, clearOptions) {
                var force = clearOptions && clearOptions.force ? clearOptions.force : false;
                if ($toastElement && (force || $(':focus', $toastElement).length === 0)) {
                    $toastElement[options.hideMethod]({
                        duration: options.hideDuration,
                        easing: options.hideEasing,
                        complete: function () { removeToast($toastElement); }
                    });
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }

            function createContainer(options) {
                $container = $('<div/>')
                    .attr('id', options.containerId)
                    .addClass(options.positionClass);

                $container.appendTo($(options.target));
                return $container;
            }

            function getDefaults() {
                return {
                    tapToDismiss: true,
                    toastClass: 'toast',
                    containerId: 'toast-container',
                    debug: false,

                    showMethod: 'fadeIn', //fadeIn, slideDown, and show are built into jQuery
                    showDuration: 300,
                    showEasing: 'swing', //swing and linear are built into jQuery
                    onShown: undefined,
                    hideMethod: 'fadeOut',
                    hideDuration: 1000,
                    hideEasing: 'swing',
                    onHidden: undefined,
                    closeMethod: false,
                    closeDuration: false,
                    closeEasing: false,
                    closeOnHover: true,

                    extendedTimeOut: 1000,
                    iconClasses: {
                        error: 'toast-error',
                        info: 'toast-info',
                        success: 'toast-success',
                        warning: 'toast-warning'
                    },
                    iconClass: 'toast-info',
                    positionClass: 'toast-top-right',
                    timeOut: 5000, // Set timeOut and extendedTimeOut to 0 to make it sticky
                    titleClass: 'toast-title',
                    messageClass: 'toast-message',
                    escapeHtml: false,
                    target: 'body',
                    closeHtml: '<button type="button">&times;</button>',
                    closeClass: 'toast-close-button',
                    newestOnTop: true,
                    preventDuplicates: false,
                    progressBar: false,
                    progressClass: 'toast-progress',
                    rtl: false
                };
            }

            function publish(args) {
                if (!listener) { return; }
                listener(args);
            }

            function notify(map) {
                var options = getOptions();
                var iconClass = map.iconClass || options.iconClass;

                if (typeof (map.optionsOverride) !== 'undefined') {
                    options = $.extend(options, map.optionsOverride);
                    iconClass = map.optionsOverride.iconClass || iconClass;
                }

                if (shouldExit(options, map)) { return; }

                toastId++;

                $container = getContainer(options, true);

                var intervalId = null;
                var $toastElement = $('<div/>');
                var $titleElement = $('<div/>');
                var $messageElement = $('<div/>');
                var $progressElement = $('<div/>');
                var $closeElement = $(options.closeHtml);
                var progressBar = {
                    intervalId: null,
                    hideEta: null,
                    maxHideTime: null
                };
                var response = {
                    toastId: toastId,
                    state: 'visible',
                    startTime: new Date(),
                    options: options,
                    map: map
                };

                personalizeToast();

                displayToast();

                handleEvents();

                publish(response);

                if (options.debug && console) {
                    console.log(response);
                }

                return $toastElement;

                function escapeHtml(source) {
                    if (source == null) {
                        source = '';
                    }

                    return source
                        .replace(/&/g, '&amp;')
                        .replace(/"/g, '&quot;')
                        .replace(/'/g, '&#39;')
                        .replace(/</g, '&lt;')
                        .replace(/>/g, '&gt;');
                }

                function personalizeToast() {
                    setIcon();
                    setTitle();
                    setMessage();
                    setCloseButton();
                    setProgressBar();
                    setRTL();
                    setSequence();
                    setAria();
                }

                function setAria() {
                    var ariaValue = '';
                    switch (map.iconClass) {
                        case 'toast-success':
                        case 'toast-info':
                            ariaValue =  'polite';
                            break;
                        default:
                            ariaValue = 'assertive';
                    }
                    $toastElement.attr('aria-live', ariaValue);
                }

                function handleEvents() {
                    if (options.closeOnHover) {
                        $toastElement.hover(stickAround, delayedHideToast);
                    }

                    if (!options.onclick && options.tapToDismiss) {
                        $toastElement.click(hideToast);
                    }

                    if (options.closeButton && $closeElement) {
                        $closeElement.click(function (event) {
                            if (event.stopPropagation) {
                                event.stopPropagation();
                            } else if (event.cancelBubble !== undefined && event.cancelBubble !== true) {
                                event.cancelBubble = true;
                            }

                            if (options.onCloseClick) {
                                options.onCloseClick(event);
                            }

                            hideToast(true);
                        });
                    }

                    if (options.onclick) {
                        $toastElement.click(function (event) {
                            options.onclick(event);
                            hideToast();
                        });
                    }
                }

                function displayToast() {
                    $toastElement.hide();

                    $toastElement[options.showMethod](
                        {duration: options.showDuration, easing: options.showEasing, complete: options.onShown}
                    );

                    if (options.timeOut > 0) {
                        intervalId = setTimeout(hideToast, options.timeOut);
                        progressBar.maxHideTime = parseFloat(options.timeOut);
                        progressBar.hideEta = new Date().getTime() + progressBar.maxHideTime;
                        if (options.progressBar) {
                            progressBar.intervalId = setInterval(updateProgress, 10);
                        }
                    }
                }

                function setIcon() {
                    if (map.iconClass) {
                        $toastElement.addClass(options.toastClass).addClass(iconClass);
                    }
                }

                function setSequence() {
                    if (options.newestOnTop) {
                        $container.prepend($toastElement);
                    } else {
                        $container.append($toastElement);
                    }
                }

                function setTitle() {
                    if (map.title) {
                        var suffix = map.title;
                        if (options.escapeHtml) {
                            suffix = escapeHtml(map.title);
                        }
                        $titleElement.append(suffix).addClass(options.titleClass);
                        $toastElement.append($titleElement);
                    }
                }

                function setMessage() {
                    if (map.message) {
                        var suffix = map.message;
                        if (options.escapeHtml) {
                            suffix = escapeHtml(map.message);
                        }
                        $messageElement.append(suffix).addClass(options.messageClass);
                        $toastElement.append($messageElement);
                    }
                }

                function setCloseButton() {
                    if (options.closeButton) {
                        $closeElement.addClass(options.closeClass).attr('role', 'button');
                        $toastElement.prepend($closeElement);
                    }
                }

                function setProgressBar() {
                    if (options.progressBar) {
                        $progressElement.addClass(options.progressClass);
                        $toastElement.prepend($progressElement);
                    }
                }

                function setRTL() {
                    if (options.rtl) {
                        $toastElement.addClass('rtl');
                    }
                }

                function shouldExit(options, map) {
                    if (options.preventDuplicates) {
                        if (map.message === previousToast) {
                            return true;
                        } else {
                            previousToast = map.message;
                        }
                    }
                    return false;
                }

                function hideToast(override) {
                    var method = override && options.closeMethod !== false ? options.closeMethod : options.hideMethod;
                    var duration = override && options.closeDuration !== false ?
                        options.closeDuration : options.hideDuration;
                    var easing = override && options.closeEasing !== false ? options.closeEasing : options.hideEasing;
                    if ($(':focus', $toastElement).length && !override) {
                        return;
                    }
                    clearTimeout(progressBar.intervalId);
                    return $toastElement[method]({
                        duration: duration,
                        easing: easing,
                        complete: function () {
                            removeToast($toastElement);
                            clearTimeout(intervalId);
                            if (options.onHidden && response.state !== 'hidden') {
                                options.onHidden();
                            }
                            response.state = 'hidden';
                            response.endTime = new Date();
                            publish(response);
                        }
                    });
                }

                function delayedHideToast() {
                    if (options.timeOut > 0 || options.extendedTimeOut > 0) {
                        intervalId = setTimeout(hideToast, options.extendedTimeOut);
                        progressBar.maxHideTime = parseFloat(options.extendedTimeOut);
                        progressBar.hideEta = new Date().getTime() + progressBar.maxHideTime;
                    }
                }

                function stickAround() {
                    clearTimeout(intervalId);
                    progressBar.hideEta = 0;
                    $toastElement.stop(true, true)[options.showMethod](
                        {duration: options.showDuration, easing: options.showEasing}
                    );
                }

                function updateProgress() {
                    var percentage = ((progressBar.hideEta - (new Date().getTime())) / progressBar.maxHideTime) * 100;
                    $progressElement.width(percentage + '%');
                }
            }

            function getOptions() {
                return $.extend({}, getDefaults(), toastr.options);
            }

            function removeToast($toastElement) {
                if (!$container) { $container = getContainer(); }
                if ($toastElement.is(':visible')) {
                    return;
                }
                $toastElement.remove();
                $toastElement = null;
                if ($container.children().length === 0) {
                    $container.remove();
                    previousToast = undefined;
                }
            }

        })();
    });
}(typeof define === 'function' && define.amd ? define : function (deps, factory) {
    if (typeof module !== 'undefined' && module.exports) { //Node
        module.exports = factory(require('jquery'));
    } else {
        window.toastr = factory(window.jQuery);
    }
}));
```

Comment: I suspect it's how you're invoking it that's causing the problem. Can you post the code you're using please?

Comment: Sure, text is updated.

Comment: `playclip` is used for testing only in this case?

Comment: Yes, I just wrote something there as name.. So I'm just calling it with onclick

Comment: If I set the timeout to 0 to make it sticky, it follows when I'm scrolling down,  but it still jumps up to the top everytime I'm calling it

Comment: Just made this and I can't duplicate your reported problem: https://jsfiddle.net/kb8cat21/. Can you post your onclick code?

Comment: Yes, you have right, I've just remembered that  I forgot the mention that I'm writing the page in an online webeditor, and it's not impossible that it added div's somewhere..

Comment: One last thing to consider is whether or not you're using an `href="#"` without `return false;` on an anchor tag for your onclick, which is why I ask if you can post that code.

Comment: Sorry, though I had it posted here, it's been now added in the beginning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your code to be like this:

`<a href="#" style="color: rgb(255,0,0,0)" onclick="playclip(); return false;" >xxxxxxxxxxxxx </a>`

However, I would reconsider using this type of javascript invokation. Take a look at this ["javascript:void(0);" vs "return false" vs "preventDefault()"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3498492/javascriptvoid0-vs-return-false-vs-preventdefault)

Comment: Gee! It worked, I will take a look at that.. Thanx a lot!

Comment: added return false; to my js function and this also did the trick