# href="javascript:void(0)" v/s href="#" onClick="return false;"

Tags: javascript, html

I have a minor confusion, as I need to use some anchor tags on navigations which on hovering will trigger some actions but on click I want them to get disabled, I referred to soo many solutions and concluded with the below two but confused which one to use:

1. `<a href="javascript:void(0)">`
2. `<a href="#" onClick="return false;">`

Comment: Version 2 will redirect your site to `#` if no JS is enabled. Version 1 won't do this.

Comment: check this link also : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3498492/javascriptvoid0-vs-return-false-vs-preventdefault

Comment: If you MUST use a link, then do this: `<a href="somelink" class="hoveronly">` using `document.getElementById("navigateContainer").addEventListener("click",function(e) { if (e.target.classList.contains("hoveronly")) e.preventDefault(); })`

Comment: Edit your question and sort out your title.

Comment: @cloned version 1 will give a 404 if JS is disabled. # would reload the page in the old days, now I think not